# How to move svg elements over html5 video and control video playback at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-video, z-index, svg-animate

```
<video id="video" width="600px" height="400px" autoplay playinline muted loop controls src="test.mp4"> 
</video>
<svg id="svg" width="600" height="400" style="position: absolute; left:8px; background:gray;opacity:0.5">
</svg>
<script>
    let svg_element = document.getElementById("svg");
    let svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    setInterval(() => {

        let player_element = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
        player_element.setAttribute("id", "player");
        player_element.setAttribute("cx", 100);
        player_element.setAttribute("cy", 100);
        player_element.setAttribute("r", 40);
        player_element.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
        player_element.setAttribute("stroke-width", 4);
        player_element.setAttribute("fill", "lightgreen");

        svg_element.appendChild(player_element);

        let animation = document.createElementNS(svgns, "animate")
        animation.setAttribute("attributeType", "XML")
        animation.setAttribute("attributeName", "cx")
        animation.setAttribute("dur", "2s")
        animation.setAttribute("to", 500)
        animation.setAttribute("from", 100)
        animation.setAttribute("fill", "freeze")
        animationID = "test"
        animation.setAttribute("id", animationID)
        player = document.getElementById("player")
        previous_animation = document.getElementById(animationID)
        if (previous_animation != null) {
            player.removeChild(previous_animation)
        }
        player.appendChild(animation)

        document.getElementById("svg").setCurrentTime(0);

    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This is a source code.
What I want to do here is to control video play.
But now, I can't control because the SVG area covers them.
What do I have to do?
The circle element must move above the video.
More circles would be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try stopping the pointer events of the svg like so

```
svg{
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate for your help. Works perfectly. Thanks again.